# Please specify mscorlib 0.0.0.0 location

Tags: telerik

I'm trying to decompile a dll, and Telerik JustDecompile tells me

```
"Please specify mscorlib 0.0.0.0 location"
```

[image]

I have never experienced this before.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thank you!